# Passing URI as parameter in Rails, which encoding is better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an API made in Rails 4.2. Thing is, the data handled by the API is not identified by ID, but by URI. So my path for the find action is

```
http://.../api/v2/taxons/:uri
```

An example of the URI I need to pass as parameter is http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/pcs2owl/gpc/C_10001334-tax.html, so my GET would be

```
http://.../api/v2/taxons/http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/pcs2owl/gpc/C_10001334-tax.html
```

Of course it doesn't work like that, so I need to encode it. Should I use CGI.escape or Base64.urlsafe_encode64? Why?